# Какую FastCGI-библиотеку для C/C++ посоветуете?

Tags: fastcgi, c++

Задался написать web-сайт на FastCGI С++. Начал рыть в интернете. Не совсем понятно, какую лучше библиотеку FastCGI для C/C++ использовать. Может что-нибудь посоветуете?

Comment: Интересно, что вы пишете? Я сейчас занимаюсь написанием небольшого web приложение на С++ и после долгих мучений остановил свой выбор на библиотеке Qt + Tufao.

Comment: Почему выбрал именно Qt + Tufao ?

Comment: наиболее полная реализация http что мне попалась, если брать тот же boost asio то там надо писать разбор http самому. Так же у Qt уже есть поддержка юникода в строках. К std:string её надо приделывать самому. А почему вы решили использовать FastCGI ?

Comment: на сервере есть сайты, написанные на PHP... чтобы они тоже работали